# react-router-dom router change the url but nothing else. All of components are not changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't solve why it doesn't work. When I clck on the link new page the url is changing but the page not (it should change to new page with div witch some content of the new page). I have to refresh it and then the component changes proprely.

version

```
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.1",
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import New from './components/NewComponents';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}>
          </Route>
          <Route patch="/new" component={New}>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

HomePage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>home page</h1>
            <Link to="/">home page</Link>
            <h1>new page</h1>
            <Link to="/New">new page</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
export default HomePage;
```

NewComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const New = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>some content of the new page</h1>
            <Link to="/">home</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
export default New;
```

Comment: You only have two routes defined in your Switch component.

Comment: The path "/New" does not match a path in your router switch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "/New" route to your switch in the App component:

```
<Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
      <Route path="/create" component={Create}></Route>
      <Route path="/New" component={New}></Route>
</Switch>
```

You also don't import the "Create" component in that module either.

Comment: I changed app.js and still nothing the link change url and nothing more ;/

Comment: You need to capitalize New in your Switch. JS is case sensitive.

Comment: nothing changed...